# syntax for passing pointer to templated function

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-passing, function-pointers

One version of my code works.  Another (which I would have thought was preferable) fails to compile.  If I declare the simple pair of functions:

```
template<class T>
void pass_function(T (*func))
{
  cout << func() << endl;
}

double func_to_pass()
{
  return(0);
}
```

I can call

```
pass_function(&func_to_pass);
```

and everything works as expected.  I know that it is "figuring out" that the template is standing for a double here even though I haven't told it that it is a double in this call.

But, if instead I call

```
pass_function<double>(&func_to_pass);
```

I, naively, would think this would be better since I am trying to tell it that the function passed as the argument will return a double.  But I get the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘pass_function(double (*)())’
```

So, clearly I am misunderstanding something about the syntax of using templates.

Comment: Perhaps you missed it, but when it "worked" in your first try, `T` wasn't `double` but `double()`. You can see that in the error message. The `()` after the `(*)` were passed down to `T`. You want to consume them in the parameter declarations, so that `T` only consumes `double`.

Comment: Ah, ha!  Yes, that's absolutely it.  Thanks @JohannesSchaub-litb !

Answer (score 0):

Change the definition like

```
template<class T>
void pass_function(T (*func)())
{
  cout << func() << endl;
}
```

Otherwise when you explicitly specify the template argument the function is specialized like

```
void pass_function( double  * );
```